# Creating FullText Index on Docx files in a FileTable

Tags: full-text-search, docx, sql-server-2012, fulltext-index

I'm working on a document storage. Therefore I plan to use SqlServer 2012 with file tables.
Now after some tests it seems like the SqlServer only indexes doc and not docx files.

I also installed the Microsoft Filter Pack 2.0.

Does somebody know how to get a docx support ? Perhaps there wold also be a way to get pdf support ??

Many Thanks in advance
Boas

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally someone posted me the solution. I post the solution to my own question because i think someone may have similar problems

Install the [Microsoft Filter Pack 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17062)

than

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'update_languages'; 
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'load_os_resources', 1;
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts';
```

> After installing the filters, run this to refresh the list.  EXEC
>   sp_fulltext_service 'update_languages';
>
> You will also likely need to refresh the filters and restart the FTS
>   service launcher:  EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'load_os_resources', 1; 
>   EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts';
>
> Finally, you’ll need to do a complete rebuild/refresh of any existing
>   full-text indexes (see ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX) to use the new filters.

s. [SqlServer Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/2346bf93-d7e9-4720-aac2-de71d866cb3e?prof=required)

Comment: Here is the official guidance from Microsoft: **How to register Microsoft Filter Pack IFilters with SQL Server** [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/945934/how-to-register-microsoft-filter-pack-ifilters-with-sql-server)

Comment: There is a service pack for this filter pack which still (2022) installs on top of it, and so I guess still probably includes useful updates: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=2460041

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above, install the Microsoft Filter Pack.

To check that it has installed correctly and what files types are currently supported you can run the following sql statement;

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_document_types
```

This gives you a list of file types supported by your database.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original question also asks about PDF, some instructions are [here](https://forums.ivanti.com/s/article/To-enable-full-text-searching-on-pdf-and-docx-documents-attached-to-the-knowledge-article-the-appropriate-ifilters-need-to-be-installed-in-MS-SQL-Server?language=en_US), but a very brief summary is:

- Download filter from ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobat/win/11.x/PDFFilter64Setup.msi, then install it
- Add `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe PDF iFilter 11 for 64-bit platforms\bin` to the system PATH variable

Other steps as for the Office filter pack in the accepted answer here (except that the PDF instructions include an extra step `EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'verify_signature', 0` after the `load_os_resources` step, I am not sure if this is necessary or not).